# How to use Ant to download/unpack jars from a single list of jars?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

How can I use Ant to download and unpack java jars while only specifying the list of jars once? The key here is having one list of jars and generating:

1. a list of URLs to download with a get task
2. a classpath/fileset of the same jars locally

I'd really only like to specify the list of jars once.

Comment: You might want to look into [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which does this sort of thing and more.

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding more parts and just stick with simple Ant if possible.

Comment: Ant is ok, but Maven 3 is the bomb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible with ant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="dependency.lib.dir" location="dependencies" />

<mkdir dir="${dependency.lib.dir}" />

<get dest="${dependency.lib.dir}">
    <url url="http://server1/lib1.jar"/> 
    <url url="http://server2/lib2.jar"/>
</get>

<fileset id="dependency.libs" dir="${dependency.lib.dir}">
    <include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>

<path id="project.debug.classpath">
    <fileset refid="dependency.libs" />
</path>
```

You can add additional sub-elements to the `<path>` if you have a local lib directory.

Comment: The problem with the snippet above is that the dependency.lib.dir could have different dependencies from a previous run which aren't desirable anymore.

Comment: @Luke, feel free to add a cleanup step that deletes the directory before hand.